# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS hangs at 43% of starting up partitioning disks

Tags: installation, server, raid

I have set up hardware raid 1 with two SAS drives using the Adptec 6405E controller. I am having a problem when installing Ubuntu 10.04 LTS  as it hangs at 43 % when partitioning disk drives. So far my Googling suggests that Ubuntu does not scan raided drives well. What can I do to finish my installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have either a flaky controller or (slightly more likely) a flaky drive.  Test both thoroughly.